# No "run" or "debug" options in Eclipse Helios

Tags: eclipse, debugging, helios

I am just switching from Visual Studio 2008 to Eclipse Helios for Mac OS X Leopard for C++ dev. I am importing a previous project with Makefile and although it compiles automatically without problems, there are no "run" or "debug" options anywhere, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends where you are looking for those menus, as illustrated in the [bug 74116](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=74116):

> 2005-12-04 14:37:28 EST
>   This has been changed to the following behavior in the "C/C++ Projects" view:
>
> - Right-click on a project or binary, gives Run/Debug with "Run Local C/C++
>     Application" as the first choice.
> - Right-click on a source file or folder gives no Run/Debug menu items
> - Right-click on another file gives the same Run/Debug menu items as in the
>     Navigator view.